# Ĉu «subteksto» aŭ «subtekstoj»?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiam oni parolas pri filmo kun subteksto, kio ekzakte estas unu subteksto? Ĉu unu mallonga frazo kiu momente aperas aŭ ĉu la tuta teksto de la filmo? Kaj tial, kiu frazo plej taŭgas?

- Ĉi tiu filmo havas anglan subtekston.
- Ĉi tiu filmo havas anglajn subtekstojn.

Mi emus preferi la unuan, sed mi ofte aŭdas ankaŭ la duan. Ĉu tio estas pro influo de aliaj lingvoj (eg, subtitles / des sous-titres)?

Comment: FWIW, my answer references PIV which is usually considered "credible" and "official". The word listed in PIV for this concept is *subtitloloj* and, as referenced in the comments on my answer PIV indicates that *teksto* usually refers to a complete work, so the *teksto* which the *subtitoloj* consist of should be considered singular.

Answer (score 4):

"Subtekstoj" sencas ĉar malsamaj tekstoj aperas depende de la momento en la video.

Ĉiuj indikiloj, kiujn mi havas, montras ke "subtekstoj" estas nun pli uzata ol "subteksto". Jen la nombroj de uzo en la Telegrama grupo "Esperantujo":

- subtekstoj: 154
- subteksto: 25
- subtitoloj: 32
- subtitolo: 5

Se mi konsideras ĉiujn Esperantajn grupojn de Telegram, kiujn mi sekvas:

- subtekstoj: 517
- subteksto: 96
- subtitoloj: 62
- subtitolo: 12

Mi trovis similan ordon en Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, Discord, Youtube: "subtekstoj" ĉiam estas la plej uzata, kaj foje "subteksto" singulare estas pli uzata ol "subtitoloj".

Mi kunlaboris al la kreado de cento da subtekstoj en Esperanto, ĉefe al tiuj de Evildea, kaj ni uzadis "subtekstoj". Evildea mem konigas la vorton per siaj videoj. Ĝi certe estas la ĉefa vorto uzata en Youtube. Do mi ne antaŭvidas ke alia vorto iĝos pli populara en la proksimaj jaroj.

Comment: Telegramo ne estas Esperantujo. Atentu ankaux ke se filmo havas "germanan subtekston" kaj "francan subtekston" - gxi havas "subtekstojn".  Vi devus kontroli la uzon, ne nur la kvanton de trafoj. Krome mi scivolas pri via respondo al la originala demando pri *kial*. Cxu simple pro tio ke nuntempe en kelkaj grupoj la plurala estas pli populara?

Comment: Subtext and subtitles are two different things in English, so I am a bit confused.  Subtext is the hidden story behind the main story, where subtitles are the letters on the screen when a movie is in a language you don't understand.    La senso estas malsama inter la du vortoj.  Kiu senso volas?

Answer (score 1):

Dum jaroj oni diris "subtitoloj" por tio. Antaŭ kelkaj jaroj, iu korektemulo plendis kaj proponis la vorton "subteksto." Tio ricevis subtenon de tre malgranda interreta grupo (iom ironie, la nomo de la grupo estis "subtitoloj") kaj ili "voĉdonis" por subteni la esprimon "subteksto."

**Subtitoloj** ankoraŭ estas uzebla kaj uzata termino.

Pri la pluraleco de "subtekstoj" - kompreneble ĝi estu singulara.

Comment: Kial ‘kompreneble’ singulara? Mi ne vidas, kial ĝi estu singulara. Ĉu ne unu subteksto estas 1-2 linioj, kiuj aperas en la malsupra parto de la ekrano (plejofte). Do tuta filmo havas multajn subtekstojn.

Comment: Mi supozas, ke oni povas argumenti ke ja temas pri multaj "subtekstaĵoj" sed "teksto" simple estas la ĉefa parto de la skribaĵo el kiu konsistas verko. Kelkaj frazoj el filmo ne estas verko. Estas klare ke oni diras "subtekstoj" pro la influo de la termino "subtitoloj." Kiel mi diris, mia prefero estas "**subtitoloj**" - kaj se vi serĉas pluralan terminon, vi povus simple uzi tion.

Comment: Tio certe havas sencon. Dankon pro la klarigo!

Comment: Mi ne komprenas kial frazoj el filmo ne estas verko. Ĝenerale subtekstoj/subtitoloj enhavas la tutan dialogon de la filmo, ne nur kelkaj frazoj (se temus pri “Parto 1: Enkonduko”, “Parto 10: Konkludo”, tiam ili estus veraj sub**titoloj**)

Comment: Mi ne diris ke "frazoj en filmo ne estas verko." Mi diris ke [nur] *kelkaj* frazoj ne estas verko. Gravas la diferenco. La subtitoloj kolektive estas **unu** teksto.

Comment: Diri “kompreneble” ĉi tie kun deklaro de via opinio sen klarigo ne estas tre helpe. Evidente la respondo ne estas “komprenebla” al mi ĉar alikaze mi ne demandus. La rakonto pri “subtitoloj” estas interesa sed eble ne multe rilatas al la demando. Ankaŭ tio estas opiniplena kaj forĵetas la proponon “subteksto” ne per argumento sed per moketo de la proponinto kiu estas “korektemulo” kiu “plendas”. Se ĝi estus artikolo de Wikipedia oni dirus ke ĝi havas tro da “weasel words”.

Comment: Pri "kompreneble", ni jam diskutis tion supre. Mi esperas ke mia respondo al Joffysloffy helpis. Mi tamen daŭre opinias ke la diferenco inter "subteksto" kaj "subtekstoj" ne gravas, ĉar la ĝusta termino estis kaj estadas "subtitoloj." La plendo pri "subtitoloj" estas ke ĝi ekzistas nur pro nacilingva influo. Ni povas diri la saman aferon pri la -j ĉe "subtekstoj." Se oni forĵetas la esprimon "subtitoloj", oni *kompreneble* devus forĵeti la j-on en "subtekstoj."